# RavenDB 3.0 index creation: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation?

Tags: indexing, expression, ravendb

This the example code to create simple index to avoid fanout index from [Ayende's post](https://ayende.com/blog/168418/what-is-new-in-ravendb-3-0-indexing-enhancements). However it cannot compile. The error is

> "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation".

If remove the cast

```
IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

from the code, it compiles but failed to generate index. It should be a common question for RavenDB 3.0 users. Any suggestions?

```
from doc in docs.Users select new {
CreditCards_Expired = (
    from docCreditCardsItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.CreditCards).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select docCreditCardsItem.Expired).ToArray(),
Roles_Name = (
    from docRolesItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.Roles).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select docRolesItem.Name).ToArray()
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
from doc in docs.Users 
select new {
    CreditCards_Expired = doc.CreditCards.Select(c=>c.Expired),
    Roles_Name = doc.Roles.Select(r=>r.Names)
}
```

Comment: And much conciser.